# How can i add data into my model which is many to many field for another model

Tags: django-models, django-forms, many-to-many

This is just a example of my models and form. my question is how i can save data in my both models only using one form. i wanted to save data through my Book Form() where in book model i have created a many to many field from Author Model and if i used this form then he is telling me to first add data in author model then only select and save data in book model. through my template i wanted to render fields from my form as author title , name , date of birth and book name and when user enter all the details it should be saved in respective models only.

```
TITLE_CHOICES = (

    ('MR', 'Mr.'),

    ('MRS', 'Mrs.'),

    ('MS', 'Ms.'),

)

class Author(models.Model):



    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)


    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)




    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):



    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)




class BookForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Book

        fields = ['name', 'authors']
```